# REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG on CLSID_WICPngDecoder

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, png, wic

I am trying to load PNGs for HBITMAP. I found this [post](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/09/displaying_a_splash_screen_with_c_part_i.html) from stackoverflow. When I run the code I get `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` on `CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICPngDecoder, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(ipDecoder), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&ipDecoder)`. I am using Visual Studio 2012 RC, I've done `CoInitlaize` and I am still getting same error what could be possibly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WIC API suggest that you create decoder from factory, rather than directly using its `CLSID`. See [IWICImagingFactory interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and sample code there.

You have options to create from file, stream or specifying container format `GUID`.

Comment: I am getting ```REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered``` while creating instance of Factory. I copy pasted the MSDN example 
```hr = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IWICImagingFactory,
    (LPVOID*)&pFactory
    ); ``` is throwing me ```REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered``` again!

Comment: I am tired of Microsoft breaking the API You need to replace ```CLSID_WICImagingFactory``` with ```CLSID_WICImagingFactory1```  I found it after lots of googling. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowswic/thread/e542d34a-a04b-455e-bd5b-957f162bab94/

Comment: Using CLSID_WICImagingFactory1 worked for me, I was getting the same Class not registered error when running it on windows embedded, even though CLSID_WICImagingFactory worked fine on win7.